# Loading Scripts Using Modernizr... Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

I'm having problems trying to load scripts using the Modernizr version of yepnope and can't get my head around why they are different. If I load the scripts using yep nope it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/yepnope.1.0.2-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
yepnope([  
    '/js/fancy-box-2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.css',  
    '/js/jquery-1.7.min.js',  
    '/js/jquery.form-defaults.js',  
    '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js',  
    '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',  
    '/js/fancy-box-2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.js',  
    '/js/functions.js',  
    'http://use.typekit.com/uoy8fub.js'
]); 
</script>
```

But if I trying using the Modernizr packaged version of yep nope I can't get anything to load... Help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/modernizr-2.0.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load([  
    '/js/fancy-box-2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.css',  
    '/js/modernizr-2.0.6.js',  
    '/js/jquery-1.7.min.js',  
    '/js/jquery.form-defaults.js',  
    '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js',  
    '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',  
    '/js/fancy-box-2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.js',  
    '/js/functions.js',  
    'http://use.typekit.com/uoy8fub.js'
]); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### UPDATE: `Modernizr.load` has been deprecated in version 3.0 in favour of using YepNope.js directly.

It's worth noting that Modernizr.load just uses the yepnope library and they are interchangeable. e.g.

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep  : 'normal.js',
  nope : ['polyfill.js', 'wrapper.js']
});

Modernizr.load({
  test : Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep  : 'normal.js',
  nope : ['polyfill.js', 'wrapper.js']
});
```

For yours, try:

```
Modernizr.load({
    load: [  
        '/js/fancy-box-2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.css',  
        '/js/jquery-1.7.min.js',  
        '/js/jquery.form-defaults.js',  
        '/js/jquery.cycle.all.js',  
        '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',  
        '/js/fancy-box-2.0.4/jquery.fancybox.js',  
        '/js/functions.js',  
        'http://use.typekit.com/uoy8fub.js'
    ]
});
```

Comment: Brilliant that works great! Looks like my syntax was a bit out. Thanks @ash-clarke

Comment: @ashclarke This does not seem to work anymore now that yepnop is deprecated

Comment: @MicFin Given that this answer is over 3 years old, I'm not surprised. Not worth a downvote though.

Comment: Chrome console: `Modernizr.load is not a function` I'm calling modernizr.js in the <head> and running this function before </body>. Why isn't it working?

Comment: `Modernizr.load has been deprecated in favor of using yepnope.js directly; from v3.0, yepnope.js must be included in the page in order for Modernizr.load to work: calling .load() will simply pass the arguments on to yepnope(); this will be removed fully in a future release` - https://modernizr.com/news/modernizr-3-new-release-site#apis

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr needs a test to decide what to do. Generally Modernizr.load is used to load polyfills so you should read this: http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#load

Comment: Ok but surely if I can use the yep nope method without a test to asynchronously load my scripts I should be able to do the same thing using the Modernizr method?