# How to load a conditional js file using modernizr now that yepnope is deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, modernizr, polyfills, yepnope

What are some good practices for loading a conditional javascript file using modernizr now that yepnope and .load are deprecated in the latest version of modernizr.

Used to be able to use the .load function.
http://modernizr.com/docs/#load

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.geolocation,
  yep : 'geo.js',
  nope: 'geo-polyfill.js'
});
```

Now .load is deprecated along with yepnope.
https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/

Reference for answer prior to yepnope being deprecated
[Loading Scripts Using Modernizr... Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909862/loading-scripts-using-modernizr-not-working)

Comment: 2 months, still unanswered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's getScript method](https://davidwalsh.name/loading-scripts-jquery). I think you could also use `.fail` instead of the `else` statement. Spent my morning figuring this out and have been trying to answer these to save people some time!

Something like this?

```
if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    jQuery.getScript("geo.js")
        //it worked! do something!
        .done(function(){
            console.log('geo.js loaded');
        });
} else {
    jQuery.getScript("geo-polyfill.js")
        //it worked! do something!
        .done(function(){
            console.log('geo-polyfill.js loaded');
        });
}
```